# Storage Buffer - int array used with [y][x] is 3 time faster than using [x][y]?

Tags: vulkan, compute-shader

As a test project, I coded a basic Consway's game of life with compute shaders (Vulkan). Basically:

- The "board" is stored in an int array, inside a Storage Buffer.

```
#define WIDTH 800
#define HEIGHT 600
#define WORKGROUP_SIZE 32

layout (local_size_x = WORKGROUP_SIZE, local_size_y = WORKGROUP_SIZE, local_size_z = 1) in;

layout(binding = 0) readonly buffer buf1 {
   int data[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
} previousBoard;

layout(binding = 1) buffer buf2 {
   int data[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
} nextBoard;
```

- A compute shader then update it every frame (one invocation per pixel).

I randomly did some changes, and I noticed that if I access the array with `data[y][x]` (from  gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy), my program is **3 time faster** than a normal access with `data[x][y]` (at least on my computer(intel UHD 620), I've got 500 fps with [x][y], against 1700 fps with [y][x]).

I spent some hours to isolate this behavior, to be sure that it wasn't a side effect. I even disassembled the Spir-v code, but found nothing interesting that help me understand. Here a diff of the shader (with [x][y], and with [y][x]): https://www.diffchecker.com/vFlkEsQp .

I'm far from understand what happen here. Is there any reason that explain such a performance gap ?

I'm not really happy using [y][x] (or should I ?), so do I have another way to achieve similar performances with [x][y]?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's almost certainly a matter of cache coherency. In GLSL, an `int[WIDTH][HEIGHT]` is an array of `HEIGHT` 1D arrays of `WIDTH` `int`s. That is row-major. So if you fetch `previousBoard.data[0][0]`, you're fetching a cache line (assuming 32-bytes) that includes maybe the next 7 elements of first row, and *none* of the second row.

Your shader is itself executing in a 2D model, with 32x32 invocations within a work-group. If the GPU executes the first row's worth of invocations (0,0 to 31,0) at the same time, it will only need to do 4 actual memory fetches. Now of course, to perform your algorithm on all of these entries, you're going to need the previous row and the next row as well, plus a cache line for the memory addresses to the right.

So in total, you'll need 15 memory fetches. That may sound like a lot.

But let's examine the case where the GPU executes the first *column's* worth of invocations: 0,0 to 0,31. Well, how many fetches do you need? You need 33 (+1 for the row below the bottom), over twice the number. Remember: the cache lines are row-major, not column-oriented.

And of course, you'll need just as many cache line writes.

That being said, the column-first invocation ordering ought to be able to pick up some performance, because the second column's invocations should be getting the same cache lines as the first. But that assumes the implementation will execute the second column's invocations as the same time. If it instead decides to fill up its execution units with more work-groups (that is, it executes column 0, column 32, column 64, column 96, etc), then you may as well not have a cache.

By contrast, the row-first ordering keeps reasonable cache coherency regardless of the order it is executed in.

There is nothing you can do to change the order of how the GPU processes your invocations. So instead, you should endeavor to make your algorithm care as little as possible about that ordering.

First, since there is no dependency between your invocations in a work group, you shouldn't make your `local_size` two-dimensional. You can play with the exact numbers to find the right value for the hardware, but 16x1 or 32x1 would probably work. There's no guarantee about the invocation order, but items in a work group that fit into a wavefront will tend to be executed together. So this will encourage it to work in a row-major fashion, executing 0,0; 1,0; etc at the same time.

Second, *please* reduce the amount of space you're using. The Game of Life has precisely two states for a cell. But you're using *thirty-two bits* to store those two states. Even if you want to avoid the pain of doing serious bit manipulation, you could at least have each byte of the `uint` be a separate cell. Extracting the Nth byte from a `uint` is a pretty trivial process.

The tricky part is going to be writing such data, since you have different invocations writing separate data. But if we assume that you have cleared the memory to zeros before starting, then you can use `atomicOr` to write the value.

Third, employ swizzling on your data. That is, instead of storing it as rows and columns, store it in blocks. The main problem you're having is because your cache biases towards the first coordinate, but your GPU is executing with a bias to the second.

Unswizzled data puts (0, 0) at byte 0, (1, 0) at byte 4, and (0, 1) at byte (4*`WIDTH`). With swizzling, what you want to do is put the four bytes 0,0; 1,0; 0,1 and 1,1 all on the same cache line. That is, (0, 1) is at byte 8, and (1, 1) is at byte 12. That way, if you fetch (1, 1), you're guaranteed to get all 4 values in the same cache line.

You can play around with the size of swizzle patterns for maximum performance.

And beyond that, you can even swizzle your `gl_InvocationID`. Instead of relying on the 2D nature of your dispatch to get the source position for an invocation, you can make your dispatch one-dimensional, and compute the `xy` position of an invocation via a swizzle matrix. So invocation 0 would be (0, 0), invocation 1 would be (1, 0), invocation 2 would be (0, 1), invocation 3 would be (1, 1), and so forth.

If you put in the work to get the most optimal data storage possible, with swizzling, then each cache line can represent an 8x8 block of data. This means that any contiguously executing group of invocations will only need at most 4 cache lines worth of data (at the corner of 4 blocks). Also, this helps solve the writing issue, since you can build data via atomic operations to `shared` variables, and simply write out the values at the end. You arrange things so that no two invocations from separate work groups need to write to the same value.

That would make everything pretty much GPU execution independent.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is precious knowledge for me. Yeah, I know storing a bool with a uint is very ugly (for my defense: "test project", "lack of time", and all the blabla haha). 

I'd really like to know more about this topic (to write efficient compute shaders), maybe could you advice me some books?