# Optimize for expensive fragment shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm rendering multiple layers of flat triangles with a raytracer in the fragment shader. The upper layers have holes, and I'm looking for a way how I can avoid running the shader for pixels that are filled already by one of the upper layers, i.e. I want only the parts of the lower layers rendered that lie in the holes in the upper layers. Of course, if there's a hole or not is not known unless the fragment shader did his thing for a layer.

As far as I understand, I cannot use early depth testing because there, the depth values are interpolated between the vertices and do not come from the fragment shader. Is there a way to "emulate" that behavior?

Comment: What do you mean by "raytracing" here? Because in raytracing, there are no "layers"; there's just geometry. For each sample of the final image, you trace a ray and hit whatever geometry is closest to the ray's origin. It's a problem that sorts itself out without having to do anything about it.

Comment: I do raytracing in an isometric world, partitioned into 3d textures. I need more height than one texture can provide, thus I render multiple layers, each with its own set of textures. If a pixel is filled by an upper layer, I don't want to raytrace it in the lower layers (again and again) just to find out that I can discard the results because it's hidden by the upper layer anyway.

Comment: Why a 3D texture? Wouldn't an SSBO, or if that's not available a buffer texture, make more sense, since they can use arbitrary amounts of memory? Also, is there something wrong with using a depth buffer here?

Comment: Depth buffer was my first thought, too, but isn't the depth test evaluated after the fragment is rendered?

Comment: Use a stencil buffer and mark each fragment into which you've already written? Do you need to adjust the depth values in the fragment shader?

Comment: @BDL: That's not going to work, since the full-screen quad used for raytracing will be the one to decide if a fragment gets written or not. And `discard` almost always shuts off early fragment tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to solve this issue is to not use layers. You are only using layers because of the limitations of using a 3D texture to store your scene data. So... don't do that.

SSBOs and buffer textures (if your hardware is too old for SSBOs) can access more memory than a 3D texture. And you could even [employ manual swizzling of the data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56213227/734069) to improve cache locality if that is viable.

---

> As far as I understand, I cannot use early depth testing because there, the depth values are interpolated between the vertices and do not come from the fragment shader.

This is correct insofar as you cannot use early depth tests, but it is incorrect as to *why*.

The "depth" provided by the VS doesn't need to be the depth of the actual fragment. You are rendering your scene in layers, presumably with each layer being a full-screen quad. By definition, *everything* in one layer of rendering is beneath everything in a lower layer. So the absolute depth value doesn't matter; what matters is whether there is *something* from a higher layer over this fragment.

So each layer could get its own depth value, with lower layers getting a lower depth value. The exact value is arbitrary and irrelevant; what matters is that higher layers have higher values.

The reason this doesn't work is this: if your raytracing algorithm detects a miss within a layer (a "hole"), you must `discard` that fragment. And the use of `discard` *at all* turns off early depth testing in most hardware, since the depth testing logic is usually tied to the depth *writing* logic (it is an atomic read/conditional-modify/conditional-write).